# Como criar gráfico de Agulhas no R?

Tags: r, plot, lattice

Estou tentando fazer um gráfico de Agulhas sugerido na Matéria de Métodos não paramétricos no estudo de Histogramas.

Achei um comando chamado `rug()`, mas parece que a ideia não essa.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se você se refere ao [needle plot](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/bidbrdug/65580/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n078fn4uh7lvdtn1p9c0hrindwfl.htm), isto é, plotar as variáveis como barras saindo do eixo zero (ou mínimo), basta colocar o parâmetro `type = h` no `plot`.

Por exemplo:

```
with(economics, plot(date, unemploy, type="h"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como você mencionou histograma,talvez você queira ver os pontos de uma única variável ao longo de uma linha. Para isso você pode usar o `dotplot` do `lattice`.

O `dotplot` plota os pontos ao longo de uma linha:

```
set.seed(1)
y = rnorm(100)
library(lattice)
dotplot(y)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode complementar o `dotplot` colocando os "needles":

```
dotplot(y, panel= function(x){
  panel.dotplot(x,factor(1))
  panel.xyplot(x, factor(1),col="black", type="h")
})
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: era Isso mesmo que eu estava procurando !

Comment: @RafaelAraujo complementei com um "needle plot" univariado, para ver a distribuição dos pontos. Se você acha que essa resposta atendeu, você pode aceitá-la clicando no símbolo de "ok" ao lado, abs.

Comment: Muito Top ! agora sim e exatamente isso que meu professor explicou! eu não conseguia achar em lugar nenhum ! Muito Obrigado mesmo !